# I don't understand the if{} statement

Tags: javascript

I made a clock in my webpage woth this code, it works fine, but I would like to know what does the if{} statment in this code, I don't understand what is it doing.

Can someone help me please? :D

```js
function startTime() {
  today = new Date();
  h = today.getHours();
  m = today.getMinutes();
  s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);

  document.getElementById('reloj').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  t = setTimeout('startTime()', 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }
  return i;
}

window.onload = function() {
  startTime();
}
```

```html
<span id="reloj"></span>
```

Comment: Seems to add a leading `0` for cosmetic reasons.

Comment: Given the formatting presented, are you aware that the `return i;}` is _not_ part of the `if` block, or is that part of what's confusing the issue?

Comment: if i is less than ten than concat a zero to the number so it is two digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` in your code is prefixing the value of `i` with a zero if it is less than 10

```
1 becomes 01
2 becomes 02
10 stays as 10
etc
```

This is so that cosmetically, the hour & minute are displayed as expected.

---

The formatting is a bit misleading - better written as

```
 function checkTime(i){
       if (i < 10) {
          i = "0" + i;
       }
       return i;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statement basically adds a preceding zero when time is in single digit, like instead of showing 9 mins, it will show as 09 mins

Answer (score 0):

well it seems that is checks that one single hour is dislpayed with two digits.

instea of 9:54 it will be 09:54

Answer (score 0):

```
i="0" + i
```

When the hours are less then 10 the i is assigned to 0 and then added to itself.As it is string it gets concatenated. The result being 09, 08 ,07 instead of 9 8 7 etc.

```js
function startTime(){
    today=new Date();
    h=today.getHours();
    m=today.getMinutes();
    s=today.getSeconds();
    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);

document.getElementById('reloj').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
   t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);}
   function checkTime(i){
       if (i<10) 
       {
       i="0" + i
       }
       return i;}
       window.onload=function(){startTime();}
```

```html
<div id="reloj"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Like checkTime() function are called in twice on your code

Minutes and Seconds are

```
1 becomes 01
2 becomes 02
And 10 stays as 10
```

So if i is less than 10 it prefixes a 0 on it .

**NB : Here I means parameter your code call this function twice once on minute and second one on Seconds**

**Hope you clear**